# Green's second identity with complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, vector-analysis, greens-relations

Let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be two smooth scalar fields:

$$\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$

$$\psi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$

Consider a closed surface $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ bounded by a contour $C$.

Let the following be the Green's second identity applied to the fields $\phi$ and $\psi$:

$$\intop_{S}\left(\phi\nabla^{2} \psi-\psi\nabla^{2}\phi\right)dS=\oint_{C}\left(\phi\boldsymbol{\nabla}\psi-\psi\boldsymbol{\nabla}\phi\right)\cdot\pmb{n}\;dl$$

1. This relation holds if one of the functions maps to complex space $\mathbb{C}$, instead of $\mathbb{R}$? Say,  $\psi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$?
2. (Stronger) the same relation holds if the two functions map to complex space ($\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $\psi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$), instead of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, it holds for the complex case because both sides are $\Bbb{C}$-bilinear with respect to $(phi,\psi)$. If that’s confusing, then just write out $\phi=\phi_1+i\phi_2$, likewise for $\psi$ and expand everything out.